# Trigonometric series convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series, absolute-convergence

I was interested in evaluating
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos n}{n+k}
$$
I saw with computation that many of such series converge. Is there a general result?
I've tried using Taylor expansion of cosine but I've realized it is meaningless since it is a good approximation only close to the origin. I was also wondering if the convergence is absolute... Any hint?

So far I have tried to use complex analysis but I guess I don't have enough background to show that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{in}}{n} = -\log (1-e^i)
$$
Why is that?

Comment: Written like this, it does not converge at all.  $i$ is the term you are summing on, not $k$ or $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show you a formal manipulation, leaving convergence details to check to you.
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos n}{n+k}&=&\text{Re}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^{in}}{n+k}\\&=&\text{Re}\left(e^{-ik}\sum_{n\geq k+1}\frac{e^{in}}{n}\right)\\&=&\text{Re}\left[e^{-ik}\left(-\log(1-e^i)-\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{e^{in}}{n}\right)\right]\\&=&\cos(k)\left(-\log(2\sin(1/2))-\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{\cos n}{n}\right)-\sin(k)\left(\frac{\pi-1}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{\sin n}{n}\right).\end{eqnarray*}$$